# Change background colors of profiler informations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, themes, color-scheme

I did install the "son of obsidian" theme in Visual Studio. Today, I used the integrated profiler and could hardly read the per-line percentage and the highlighting was a bit off. No doubt this is because of the theme.

I have tried to find the relevant config entry within the options, but I had no luck so far. Where can I configure the background color of the percentages and the highlight color?

Here is a screenshot to illustrate my problem:

[image: The places where I want to define other colors]

Meanwhile, I tried to change it using the xml File (.vssettings) directly, bit no luck so far. I changed all the colors in the xml to red but the background color of the bar won't change. The textcolor is the same as the normal textcolor in the editor. If that is white or a light gray, the profiling information is hardly legible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for anyone else who happens to have this problem here is the fix:

In VS2013: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors.

Under the settings for Text Editor in the Display Items box, you can change the margin by editing the Indicator Margin.